# Why are native views of Cordova plugins stacked an how can I disable them

Tags: ios, cordova, wikitude, cordova-ios

After the update from cordova 8 to 9 and cordova-ios 4 to 5 the behavior of plugins (wikitude, scanbot) with native iOS views changed. The plugins has not been updated, so it must be caused by the Cordova update.

Before the update, the plugins created their views in fullscreen mode. After the update, they are shown as a card over the webView (like the playing song view in the music app)

This is a screenshot with the web view in the background, and the native view from the wikitude plugin as overlay, which I can close by swiping down - https://ibb.co/QjPTQ8B

The problem is: This kind of UI prevents any touch move events inside  the native view, because it always passes the move event to the view and the swipe-down function.

How can I disable this behavior? I want back the fullscreen view.

Or do you have some advices where I have to search?

- cordova 9 and cordova-ios 5 release notes do not say something about that
- how is this UI pattern/behavior called?
- can I find something useful in the view hierarchy in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default modal presentation style was changed in iOS 13. So it's actually a kind of silent breaking change for some available plugins out there ("Thanks Tim Apple ;-)").

For the scanbot sdk plugin: we have just fixed that in the latest release `cordova-plugin-scanbot-sdk@3.2.2`.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you!!
I think it's more a xcode issue, beause the earlier released app on iOS 13 still uses fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

```
[viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
```

This has to be set in the plugin code, then its loaded in fullscreen.